# TLS handshake failure (40) solved by removing intermediate certificate from server?

Tags: tls, certificates, certificate-authority, cipher-selection

I'd like to better understand my workaround, and confirm that it's secure.

**Problem**

- I have a crt file containing a root and intermediate certificate installed on my server (I have limited access to the server - its running in a third party docker container running Wildfly).
- I have the root CA certificate installed on my client.
- Client requests to the server fail with a TLS handshake failure (40): Chrome reports this as ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

**Solution**

- I remove the intermediate certificate from the server and add the intermediate CA certificate to my client and requests now succeed

My current best guess is that the cipher suite required by the intermediate certificate is not supported on the server, but I don't understand enough about TLS to explain how simply ripping the intermediate certificate out can solve the problem safely, if it does.  I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Sounds strange for me. Based on this I would suggest that while doing what you describe you made some other change  too (which you might not have been aware) which actually fixed the problem or that some other stuff was changed at the same time (like some firewall settings or similar). If you revert your fix, does the problem occur again?

Comment: Make sure certs are in the correct order on the server; server cert followed by intermediate.  I'd suggest sniffing the conversation and viewing it in Wireshark so you can see the order they're in on the wire.  If you have them reversed, that would likely cause Chrome to fail to validate them.

Comment: @gowenfawr: if the server rejects with alert 40 it doesn't send the certificates at all so you can't see them with wireshark, or anything else. This error does not relate to any Chrome validation. OP: the first file probably had an error that caused WIldfly to not load the cert _at all_; in that case JSSE only accepts requests using 'anonymous' ciphersuites (in TLS1.2 or below only) which no browser ever offers; most other clients don't, but some can be configured to, if you had tried that before changing. The other way to determine is to look at server log(s).